# Extract File extensions using regular expression in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I wanna write a regular expression that can extract file types from a string.

the string is like:

> Text Files
>   (*.prn;*.txt;*.rtf;*.csv;*.wq1)|*.prn;*.txt;*.rtf;*.csv;*.wq1|PDF
>   Files (*.pdf)|*.pdf|Excel Files
>   (*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm;*.xlsb;*.xlam;*.xltx;*.xltm;*.xlw)

result e.g.

> .prn

Comment: Why not use the built in classes?

Comment: @Matt Ellen, perhaps because it doesn't fulfill the requirements at all... The OP is not trying to extract the extension from a file name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the dialog filterformat.

The extensions already appear twice (first appearance is unreliable) and when you try to handle this with a RegEx directly you'll have to think about

```
 Text.Files (.prn;.txt;.rtf;.csv;.wq1)|.prn;.txt;.rtf;.csv;.wq1|
```

etc.

It looks safer to follow the known structure:

```
string filter = "Text Files (.prn;.txt;.rtf;.csv;.wq1)|.prn;.txt;.rtf;.csv;.wq1|PDF Files (.pdf)|.pdf|Excel Files (.xls;.xlsx;.xlsm;.xlsb;.xlam;.xltx;.xltm;.xlw)";

string[] filterParts = filter.Split("|");

// go through the odd sections
for (int i = 1; i < filterParts.Length; i += 2)
{
    // approx, you may want some validation here first
    string filterPart = filterParts[i];

    string[] fileTypes = filterPart.Split(";");
    // add to collection
}
```

This (only) requires that the filter string has the correct syntax.

Comment: Thanks, I used split instead of regex.

Answer (score 0):

```
Regex extensionRegex = new Regex(@"\.\w+");
foreach(Match m in extensionRegex.Matches(text))
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
}
```

Comment: +1: A good start, but it won't work for otherwise legal file extensions such as `.$$$`.

Comment: @Jon, true. You would have to replace "\w" with a group containing all legal characters

Comment: You might want to incorporate something like `string.Format("[^{0}]+", Regex.Escape(System.IO.Path.InvalidPathChars))`.

Comment: This isn't going to work for any file with multiple periods in the name, which is legal and fairly common.

Comment: @Jon: That's not going to work in this case because, for example, the `;` character that's used as a delimiter here is perfectly legal as part of a filename/extension.

Comment: @LukeH, good point... but then it means that the pattern for file dialog filters is intrinsically broken! Admittedly sane people wouldn't use a semi-colon as part of a file extension

Comment: @LukeH: True. In the general case I don't think the problem can be solved, and as a practical solution Thomas's answer could certainly be good enough.

Answer (score 0):

If that string format you have there is fairly fixed, then the following should work:

```
\.[^.;)]+
```